# Tornado asyncio questions

Tags: tornado

Currently all my functions are decorated with `@tornado.gen.coroutine` which i then yield. I want to move to the newer `async/await`.

To move to async does that mean that i need to start the Tornado with the asyncio IOLoop as shown in documentation:

```
from tornado.platform.asyncio import AsyncIOMainLoop
import asyncio
AsyncIOMainLoop().install()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

I changed some co-routines to use `async/await` instead of `yield` this seemed to work on the old Tornado IOLoop why is that if i didn't start the Tornado engine explicitly with asyncio?

In my current code I have a place where I yield a list of coroutines:

```
responses=yield [wrap(httpClient,url) for url in somelist]
```

how could this line be achieved with await?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do *not* need to use asyncio's event loop, Tornado can run native coroutines (defined with `async def`) using the Tornado event loop.

You can await a list of coroutines like:

```
await tornado.gen.multi([wrap(httpClient,url) for url in somelist])
```

[More information about Tornado and native coroutines is in the docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html#python-3-5-async-and-await).

Comment: Hi Jesse, but why then is there the asyncio loop? as documented: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/asyncio.html?highlight=asyncio it looks like you can explicitly start a AsyncIOMainLoop. Why is this an option then if you can just use async and await with the normal IOLoop out of the box?

Comment: This is not about "async" and "await". It's about using other libraries written for the asyncio event loop that depend on its particular APIs, and integrating those asyncio-specific libraries with Tornado-specific libraries or your Tornado-specific code.